# javascript code is only working with mozzila firefox?

Tags: javascript

On my website, I have an image viewer.  Every time the user click the left or right button the url of the page will be changed aromatically.  The image src uses a specific number from the url of the current page (the only number in the url).  Below I have provided the code I am using. The code is working perfectly, but it is only working on mozilla firefox. How can I fix it in order to make it work for all browsers. The problem on the other browsers is that the image do not show up.

```
<img src="" id="image" >
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('image').src ="Images/"+location.href.match(/\d+/)+".jpg";
        <br/>
        document.wrriteln(location.href.match(/\d+/)+".jpg");
    </script>
    <br/>
    <script>
    var url = location.href;
    function nextImage() {
        return(url.replace(/(\d+)(\.html)$/, function(str, p1, p2) {
            return((Number(p1) + 1) + p2);
        }));
    }
    function prevImage() {
        return(url.replace(/(\d+)(\.html)$/, function(str, p1, p2) {
            return((Number(p1) - 1) + p2);
        }));
    }
    </script>
      <a href="javascript: window.location.href = prevImage();"> <img border="0" src="Assets/Left.png" /></a>
      <a href="javascript: window.location.href = nextImage();"> <img border="0" src="Assets/Right.png"/></a>
```

Comment: I suggest running your code through a linter/validator - you're going to get a lot of errors/warnings. There is a lot wrong with your approach - e.g. don't use javascript in href attributes - use javascript to _update_ the href - (though why use js at all if you are going to ask the user to do a full page load anyway)

Comment: I am new using javascript and this is my first project. Basically I do not know any other alternatives.

Comment: start from the point of view that your page should work _without_ javascript first. Use javascript to enhance the user experience, not leave them with nothing if your js (or their browser, though that's not the case here) doesn't work correctly. You may also simply use jquery as it'll save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: I am still learning js, I will learn jquery next. by the way do you know the answer to my problem ?

Comment: if you want to learn javascript as a language - read [the good parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do), install a cli, and don't use a browser for testing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should do is

```
<a href="#" id="prevImageControl">
```

and in the javascript block do

```
prevImageClick = function()
{
    window.location.href = prevImage();
}

var prevImageControl = document.getElementById('prevImageControl');
prevImageControl.addEventListener('click', prevImageClick);
```

repeat for nextImage()

Comment: since there is no logic in prevImageClick - it could set the a.href, be called on load and no event listener is required. This would be the most efficient/robust solution.

Comment: 1 - You really never know when you'll add more code. My image handlers aren't really that shallow. 2 - I'm showing the newbie the currently accepted method for registering event handlers.

Comment: I'm sorry but demonstrating how to change the href of a link onclick and then change window.location is not teaching anything that aught to be taught.

Comment: What I'm saying is that normally changing the link is not the only behavior that you'll add.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change these:

```
<a href="javascript: window.location.href = prevImage();"> <img border="0" src="Assets/Left.png" /></a>
<a href="javascript: window.location.href = nextImage();"> <img border="0" src="Assets/Right.png"/></a>
```

To onclick events.

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: window.location.href = prevImage();return false;"> <img border="0" src="Assets/Left.png" /></a>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: window.location.href = nextImage();return false;"> <img border="0" src="Assets/Right.png"/></a>
```

Or better still, put them into functions.

Answer (score 0):

you have a double r in document.wrriteln